# on iphone - jquery to open/close nested nav

Tags: jquery, iphone, nav

I'm building a mobile website that has a nested nav at the top. I want the sub-nav to pop up when the user taps on its parent li. Here's my trouble: I need it to close when anything otuside of the sub-nav is tapped, including the li that initally opened it.

What I've tried:

- fadeToggle and other toggles: the sub-nav only closes when the parent li is tapped    again.
- hover(): Will not close sub-nav at all.

A sample of what my nav looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li id="open"><a href="#">one</a>
        <nav><ul>...</ul></nav>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ui>
```

And here's the hover jquery I've tried:

```
$("li#open").hover(
    function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); $("nav").show(); },
    function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); $("nav").hide(); }
);
```

I'm not comfortable enough with jquery and javascript to write my own functions, but there must be some way to write one that will say, anything but 'nav' will hide 'nav'. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this for iphone only (tagged iphone) or all mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
$("li#open").click(function (event) { 
    // prevent default
    event.preventDefault();
    // if #open has class active, then remove it if not then add it
    if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
);

$(document).click(function() {
    // if #open has class active then remove it
});
```

class active should be displaying the menu and the menu is display none by default. this way when you add class active, the menu will show

this works for one menu item if you have multiple items, then the code needs to change a bit. If this is only for iOS then you can use touchstart and touchend instead of click

```
$("li#open").live('touchstart', function (event) { // function content }
```

touchstart is triggered when you touch the screen and when your finger leaves the screen, touchend is triggered

Comment: I'll give your first method a try. touchstart isn't what I'm looking for though, because I want to manipulate 2 distinct taps, not one long tap.

Comment: @MaryPelletier touchstart can be used for any number of tabs, you just need to bind it to them. if you have the same class for multiple tabs then bind it to that class. You can always access the tab that the person has touched and turn off the menu that is currently open from other tabs

Comment: Huangism - I said tap, not tab. I understand how touchstart and touchend work, it's just not the functionality that I'm looking for. Your first suggestion works partially- the first conditional works on a desktop browser, but the (document).click portion doesn't work. On mobile safari, none of it works.

Comment: @MaryPelletier then bind touchstart to document